# Requesting assist with postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

Hey everyone. Here is my situation... I need to craft a sql query against a postgresql server that will return all records created within the past 5 minutes, rounded down to the lowest minute. So if cron kicks the query off at 12:05:25.000, it needs to query all records created since 12:00:00.000. So I guess I really have two issues.

Here is the current query:

```
select * from callhistory where created>date_trunc('minute', timestamp (current_timestamp-interval '5' minute));
```

It doesn't return anything. Also, the format of the created field is "2011-05-18 18:11:32.024."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is your [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is a bit off:

```
select *
from callhistory
where created > date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '5' minute)
```

You could also use [`now()` in place of `current_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
select *
from callhistory
where created > date_trunc('minute', now() - interval '5' minute)
```

And an example:

```
=> create table stuff (created timestamp not null);
=> insert into stuff (created) values (current_timestamp);
-- Wait a could seconds...
=> insert into stuff (created) values (current_timestamp);
=> select * from stuff where created > date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '5' minute);
          created           
----------------------------
 2011-06-01 11:32:55.672027
 2011-06-01 11:33:00.182953
=> select * from stuff where created > date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '7' day);
          created           
----------------------------
 2011-06-01 11:32:55.672027
 2011-06-01 11:33:00.182953
```

**UPDATE**: Looks like PostgreSQL version 8 is a little stricter on the format for `interval`, the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) says that you should use `interval '$n $unit'` where `$n` is the number of things and `$unit` is the time unit. Version 9 allows you to say `interval '$n' $unit` without complaint but version 8 converts your interval to 0 if you don't use the documented format. So, you should use this for both version 8 and version 9:

```
select *
from callhistory
where created > date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '5 minute')
```

Comment: Hm, I tried it and am still getting no results. I also tried using interval '7' day and interval '1' month with no luck. The latest record was created on the 27th, so one of them should have returned something. Could it have to do with the format of the timestamp including the timezone?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is fine - `now()`, although fully equivalent, is non-standard.

Comment: @Milen: That's why I corrected my comments about `current_timestamp` in my original answer.

Comment: Sadly I can't include the schema because its for a proprietary vendor DB :( Essentially the fields are like this:
created|modified|call_stat_1|call_stat_2|call_stat_3|...|call_stat_N
Basically i need to fetch all of the records that have been created in the past 5 minutes. However due to the number of records, precision is important (hence making sure that it runs for exactly a 5 minute span of time).

Comment: @Matthew: Can you at least tell us what the column type for `created` is and include some sample data?

Comment: `created | timestamp without time zone | not null` Some sample values=(2011-05-18 18:11:32.024|2011-05-18 18:51:32.841|2011-05-18 18:51:32.847|2011-05-18 18:51:33.548) - they are separated by bars inside the parens due to the inability to format the comment.

Comment: @Matthew: The query works fine (see my update) so maybe your interval doesn't match your data.

Comment: Weird... `select created from callhistory;` returns 2011-06-01 14:33:20.865, 2011-06-01 14:33:20.979, ..., 2011-06-01 14:33:15.475. But when searching with the query `select * from callhistory where created > date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '7' day);` 0 rows are returned. Can you expound a bit on the interval not matching the data?

Comment: @Matthew: What do you get if you `select date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '7' day);` from `psql`? And what does `select current_timestamp;` say?

Comment: `select date_trunc('minute', current_timestamp - interval '7' day),current_timestamp;
       date_trunc       |              now              
------------------------+-------------------------------
 2011-06-01 16:30:00-04 | 2011-06-01 16:30:54.147379-04` - strange.

Comment: @Matthew: Here's a wild guess, you're using PostgreSQL version 8, right?

Comment: @Matthew: See my update for a version that should work with PostgreSQL 8. Sorry, I should have spotted that earlier.

Comment: Why all the date_trunc?  What's wrong with:
where created > now() - interval '5 minutes' ?

Comment: @Scott: I assumed that was one of Matthew's requirements and that he wanted everything done at a 1 minute resolution. I kept them around because they were in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample test I did against a PostgreSQL 8.3 server. You did not mention the version you are running.

```
select current_timestamp, to_char((current_timestamp - '5 minutes'::interval), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:00')::timestamp;
```

The interval deducts the 5 minutes and to_char() method rounds down to the closest minute. If this is what you are looking for, then the query should look as follows:

```
select * from callhistory where created > to_char((current_timestamp - '5 minutes'::interval), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:00')::timestamp
```